# $(-1)^{[n/2]} = (-1)^{\frac{n^2 +3n}{2}}$ is this true for all natural numbers$?$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

$(-1)^{[n/2]} = (-1)^{\frac{n^2 +3n}{2}}$ is this true for all natural numbers$?$ where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function

Determinant of $n \times n$ backward identity matrix is given by $(-1)^{[n/2]}$ I read in a book that its determinant is $(-1)^{\frac{n^2 +3n}{2}}$. I also checked it for some values of n. And this comes out to be equal.

So in general, it must be true that $(-1)^{[n/2]} = (-1)^{\frac{n^2 +3n}{2}}$.

Is there any proof or some basic reasoning about this$?$

Comment: Consider even $n$. Consider odd $n$. What can you conclude?

Comment: classify n into 4 classes according to remainder divided by 4.